# What is the best practice to outsource app translation in Android?

Tags: android, localization, android-xml

What is in your opinion the best practice to outsource strings translation for an Android app that must support several languages?

Let's assume that translators are not technicians so I can't feed them with XML (XLS should be fine however) and that they're not working in my company so I should send them "something" by Email and they should return me "something" by Email.

Furthermore I have a sparse translation set as for now: I'm native Italian and I speak English so while writing code I populate the values-it/strings.xml fully and the values/strings.xml partially, but nothing of values-de/strings.xml for example.

Comment: Will Google Translation API be of some use to you?

Comment: does this sound like an option http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/services/software-localization/android-localization/

Comment: thanks mariomario, I knew about icanlocalize but I already have translators, I'm just looking for a "common tool" to let them translate.

Comment: hey did you already found something, and was my suggestion of crowdin of any use.

Comment: I have the same question as you. I want to export my strings into a spreadsheet or similar format for easy translation, then convert the result back to XML. I've put a bounty on this question, lets see if it gets some more attention.

Comment: This is a good to convert xml to xls and vice versa.
https://github.com/hamsterksu/AndroidLangTool

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: https://crowdin.com it has a good ui for none technical people and it creates the xml files of the translations to be downloaded.
You can also let the translations be proof read.

Comment: mm thanks again, I was wondering somthing like exporting strings.xml to excel, giving to the translators and import back to strings.xml, does such a tool exist?

Comment: well you could do that, but I have a feeling that you need to make it your self :s

Comment: @Maurix, here is that tool: https://github.com/hamsterksu/AndroidLangTool

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what I need but searching for an answer I found myself this tool:

http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/

it integrates in Eclipse and shows an editor in excel-like fashion with strings in the rows and languages in the columns.

Comment: interesting idea, but I guess we don't want to require that the translators install Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use a Google Spreadsheet, with a tab for each language.

Copy the first column with the same tags for each tab, which are the ids and the second column with the translation.

To help them start, add English (which i suppose you already have) to the first tab.

**Update:**

To export from the Spreadsheet to an XML valid file, simply export it to CSV and it is trivial to create a Java class that reads the csv and converts it to a valid XML file. If you need references I can find some examples.

Comment: What's the best way to import/export this to the Android string resource XML format?

Comment: Updated the answer with that subject.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem myself at work. While researching for solutions I found [Open Language Tools](http://open-language-tools.java.net/). I did not have an opportunity to try it out, however, as I moved on to other things. So I don't know how it fits into Android's resource framework.

The best part is it's based on open standards.

> The Open Language Tools are a set of translation tools that aim to
>   make the task of translating software and documentation a lot easier.
>   Initially, they comprise of a full-featured XLIFF Translation Editor
>   and a set of XLIFF file-filters for a number of documentation and
>   software file formats.

Other related links from my bookmarks:

- [Open Language Tools XLIFF Translation Editor (OTE)](http://www.siberlogic.com/integrations/SunOLT.html?auth11#close=1)
- [xliffRoundTrip Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xliffroundtrip/)

### Converting between XML and Excel:

You can use Excel's import option to import any XML file into Excel. E.g., in Excel 2002, I can select `Data->Import External Data->Import Data` menu option to import the Strings.xml file. However, it's better to keep `<string>` & `<string-array>` in separate XML files to make the conversion easier.